# td copying the width from other td

Tags: html, css

I want to create a monopoly play board, but when the 2nd td keeps having `width: 70%` which is only used if the element contains `class="middle"`. But my first row doesn't containt the class `.middle` yet it takes over the 70%.

https://jsfiddle.net/jwe8Lpo5/1/

It's the one containing "Smith" that should have `width: 7.5%`.

Comment: this is how table cells behave ... you may wanna use divs or list

Comment: If your rows are going to have an uneven amount of cells, then you need to use `colspan` instead of `width`. You can't have one row with 10 cells and one row with 3.

Comment: @Santi Thanks, gonna look it up.

Comment: @C.Ronaldo no problem. Perhaps [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/jwe8Lpo5/2/) should push you in the right direction.

Comment: @Santi Thank you, if you post this as answer I can accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is due to the uneven amount of columns for each row. You have to think of your `<td>` elements as *columns*. If you set 70% width on one `<td>`, you are setting the width of that *column* to 70%.

What you're looking for is not width, but more likely [**colspan**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp), which allows a `<td>` to span across multiple columns.

Something like this should get you closer to your desired appearance:

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td.top-bottom {
    height: 15%;
    width: 7.5%;
}

td.side {
    width: 15%;
}

td.middle {
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="top-bottom">Jill</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Smith</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">50</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Jill</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Smith</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">50</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Jill</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Smith</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">50</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Jill</td>
        <td class="top-bottom">Smith</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="side">Jiaaall</td>
        <td colspan="9">Saamith</td>
        <td class="side">5aa0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="side">Jaaill</td>
        <td colspan="9">aaaSmith</td>
        <td class="side">5aa0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="side">Jiaaall</td>
        <td colspan="9">Smaaith</td>
        <td class="side">5aa0</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```